# How often does puppet with splay run?

Tags: puppet

Say I turn on the `splay` option for a puppet agent with:

```
sudo puppet config set splay true --section agent
```

Then I run:

```
/usr/local/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize
```

From what I understand `splay` causes the check-in time to randomised.

I'm wondering how this randomness is calculated? Is it a random time in the next, hour, day, week, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading [here](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/orchestration_puppet.html#run-puppet-on-demand), that the default time is randomised between the time the command is run and **2 minutes** after that.

> When the service is stopped, the selected nodes will randomly stagger
>   the start of their runs (“splay”) over a default interval of two
>   minutes. If you wish, you can specify special options, including a
>   longer interval (“splaylimit”). You can also set the force option to
>   true if you want the selected nodes to start immediately. This
>   behavior is more flexible and resilient.

---

The 2 minutes can be modified with:

```
LIMIT=60
sudo puppet config set splaylimit $LIMIT --section agent
```